# Hosting .NET Core Web Api

Tags: .net, service, .net-core, self-hosting, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to host a .NET Core WEB API outside IIS. I came to know there are two hosting options under self hosting.

```
 1. Hosting as windows service
 2. Hosting as Console application.
```

I am getting error while adding package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices. It says the package is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0. Is windows service hosting possible with .NET Core. ?

I tried the commands for self hosting.

```
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

As far as my understanding, these commands need to be run against the entire source code which not possible in normal application deployment scenario. Is there any alternate steps that can be followed for self hosting remotely.?

Comment: Please ask only 1 question per post. If you have more than one question, search and post those separately.

Comment: Windows service would require you compile to full framework.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to steer toward a console app for the sake simplicity in implementation. I would follow this tutorial if you choose to do so:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-8-0

You can then create an executable if you want to make your application automated.

[Make .net core console app a single .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967697/make-net-core-console-app-a-single-exe)

You can also add an API connection for interaction with other resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient