# Make .net core console app a single .exe

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a C# .NET Core 2.0 console app.  I want to deploy it so it is a single `.exe` file with all associated `.dll` included in the `.exe`.

Is this possible?

The reason I want to do this is I have made several console apps and I want to put them in the same folder so that only 1 path entry is required to make them available from the command line.

If I publish with `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64` I get an `.exe` but I also get a load of other files.

Is there anyway to either move all these associated files to a named subfolder or to wrap them all up in a single file?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a duplicate, because of the date difference and the fact that things have probably moved on since then, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153226/how-to-create-a-dotnet-core-single-executable) may be worth a look.

Comment: [Fody Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) can be generally be used for this but unfortunately, it does not support .NET Standard yet. [Here is an open issue about it](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/227)

Comment: CoreRT and Costura look interesting.  I will try both and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Could be of interest to know that with dotnet core 3.0 this is possible without third party tools. Using dotnet core 3.0 you can run `dotnet publish -r win10-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true` to get a single x64 self-contained windows binary, or `dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained=false /p:PublishSingleFile=true` to not include the runtime. You can read more about it in the [GA document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables) or the [design specification](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/single-file/design.md)

Answer (score 13):

I know this question is a few years old but now finally, this is possible with .NET Core.

You can achieve this in two different ways

1. In a console/terminal

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

2. Publish the application

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can find more info from the links below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/

Comment: Note: .exe file size for `hello world` console app jumps from 145 KB to 62 MB, to reduce the file size, you can [trim unused code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trim-self-contained) (last checkbox in the last image, it is: `trim unused code` VS 2023 V.17.6.4), file size trimmed to 11 MB

Answer (score 7):

No, right now .NET Core does not support producing a single .exe that contains your entire application.

And don't be confused when you read about `self-contained` apps. Self-contained means that application is published for a specific OS by specifying the target runtime (like `-r win10-x64`) and this allows not to have the .NET Core as the shared runtime in the target machines.

Answer (score 3):

You can pack your applications in a single executable with the help of BoxedApp.
[Here is a guide](https://www.boxedapp.com/boxedapppacker/usecases/pack_dotnet_core_into_single_exe.html) on how to do this

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called [Warp](https://github.com/dgiagio/warp) that wraps up the package into a single application file.

(And hopefully it will be supported in .NET Core 3+ as a Single-File feature:
https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/single-file/design.md)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your csproj file and add these

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Now when you do a publish `dotnet publish -c Release`

You should see a single exe in your bin/release folder.